# Why is only the first boxplot changing color?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I've written the following code to create a boxplot with multiple groups. I want each plot to be a different specified color but I can only seem to alter the first one in the series. I can change the first "blue" to any color but the other plots always stay gray. Any idea what I need to fix?

```
ggplot(Boxplots, aes(x=SiteName, y= Concentration, fill=SiteName)) +
 geom_boxplot() +
 scale_y_log10() +
 theme_bw() +
 scale_fill_manual(breaks= Boxplots$SiteName,
                   values= c("blue", "cornflowerblue","cyan", "red", "darkred", "maroon"))
```

[image]

Comment: We can only guess without your data, but I suspect the first several rows of your data frame are all `BEAV-O1`, so the breaks you are setting for all your colors are the same location. Try `breaks= unique(Boxplots$SiteName)` inside `scale_fill_manual`. Or just remove `breaks` entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add **fill=SiteName** to `geom_boxplot()` and remove **breaks= Boxplots$SiteName**, from `scale_fill_manual()`like this:

```
 ggplot(Boxplots, aes(x=SiteName, y= Concentration,fill=Boxplots$SiteName)) +
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Boxplots$SiteName)) + scale_y_log10() + theme_bw() +
       scale_fill_manual(values= c("blue", "cornflowerblue","cyan", 
       "red", "darkred", "maroon"))
```

Comment: ggplot(Boxplots, aes(x=SiteName, y= Concentration, fill=Boxplots$SiteName)) + geom_boxplot() + scale_y_log10() + theme_bw() + scale_fill_manual(values= c("blue", "cyan","cornflowerblue", "red", "maroon", "darkred"))

Comment: Removing the "breaks=Boxplots$SiteName" did the trick! Thanks!